# Are router mounting holes standard?

Tags: routers

I just bought a used table saw and a previous owner extended the table and in the extension put holes to mount a router underneath.  There's a 1.5-2" center hole and several counter-sunk holes around it for mounting screws/bolts.  I don't know whether the spacing of those holes is fairly standard across router brands or if I'm going to have trouble finding a router to mount in the existing holes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not standard, but there seem to be a few common patterns.

Rockler's website has a guide for [choosing a mounting plate](http://www.rockler.com/rockler-router-table-plates-choose-the-plate-that-best-fits-your-application) for your router. These are the router models that they support:

> - Group A routers: Makita 1100; Milwaukee 5615-5624; DeWalt 616-618; Bosch 1617-1618; Ridgid 2930 Combo Kit; Hitachi M12VC (fixed and kit); Porter-Cable 690, 890, 7529, 97529 and 8529. Note: Current models of the Porter-Cable 892 require at least two screws  to be 1/2" long versus 5/8".
> - Group B routers: DeWalt DW621 and DW621K; Craftsman Standard; Freud FT 1700E and 1702VCEK
> - Group C routers: Porter-Cable 7518, 7519, 7538 and 7539; Milwaukee 5625-20; Triton TRA001 and MOF001
> - Group D routers: Bosch 1619-1619EV; Freud FT2000; DeWalt 625

They also offer blanks that you can drill to fit your router if it's not in the above lists.

On the "Tech Spec" tab of that page, they have PDFs that show the pattern for each of the four above groups, so if you measure the spacing of the holes in your table, you may be able to find one that fits.

Comment: Some routers want additional holes beyond those used to mount them to the plate. Mine came with "above-the-table" adjustment capability, and needed holes to let the crank access both the height adjustment and the spindle lock.

Comment: The holes in the table definitely match Group C. Looking for routers on Craigslist, I see a lot of Skil and Craftsman (I know, not great but they'll get me started) which, of course, aren't listed by Rockler. Anyone have a Skil or Craftsman? Can you tell me if it is mounted by four holes in a square?

Comment: The link in the answer post is no longer works. Here is an updated link: https://www.rockler.com/learn/router-plate-buying-guide I haven't been able to find the Tech Spec tab on the new link for the exact blueprints.